# Else and If mysql and php error

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to return a not available when the some data is not present but i think something is wrong in my code

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '".$id."' AND type = 'new'";
if(!empty($sql))
{
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    echo utf8_encode($row['bookreview']);
}
else
{
    echo "<div style='text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255,255);'><font style='color: rgb(204, 0, 0);' size='+3'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>review not not available.</span></font><br>";
}
```

If review is available it return the review while if not available the " review not available" does not echo.

Comment: You're using the if statement with the $sql value and allways has data, use $result instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `$sql` variable contains a string which is assigned prior to checking if it is empty. It will never be empty in this case.

Maybe what you are trying to do is check the number of results returned from the query? In order for that to happen, you have to run the query first. Here is a quick (off the top of my head) example with mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '".$id."' AND type = 'new'";

// Run query
if ( $result = $mysqli->query($sql) )
{
   // We got results
   var_dump($result);
   $result->close();
}
else
{
   // No results
   echo("Oops. Nothing here.");
}
```

To avoid SQL injection, I recommend learning about PDO and how to write prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$id  = (int) $_GET['id']; // important !
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = ' . $id. ' AND type = "new"';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    echo utf8_encode($row['bookreview']);
} else {
    echo "<div style='text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255,255);'><font style='color: rgb(204, 0, 0);' size='+3'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>review not not available.</span></font><br>";
}
```

It's important tu cast GET parameters to specified type (`int` here) to avoid SQL Injection !

With `mysql_num_rows` you can check how many rows were returned with your query. You have to do a query to check it. Checking if `$sql` variable is empty is useless because it is just string that is always 'full' - it containst your query statement.

Comment: The num rows comparison is more expensive than just checking the result but it should work. You also guard against SQL injection but please explain it in your answer!

Comment: hi, i am getting Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @markus-tharkun I have explained it.
@meandme So you have some error in your query, `mysql_query` returns then `false`.

Comment: Cool, now it's an answer, before it was just a piece of code.

Comment: @markus-tharkun It was already before you have posted your comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually checking if **string is empty**, not the result set, see it?

```
!empty("any string")
```

will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql` is never going to be empty.. because is an string that you just set. You might want to do:

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '".intval($id)."' AND type = 'new'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!empty($result) and mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    echo utf8_encode($row['bookreview']);
}
else
{
    echo "<div style='text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255,255);'><font style='color: rgb(204, 0, 0);' size='+3'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>review not not available.</span></font><br>";
}
```

Comment: You're copy-pasting bad practice. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I copy from the question to edit the code.. what's wrong with that? If you suggested I copied from another answer you are wrong.. as we answered within 10 seconds difference.. Though you are right about the SQL Injection.. I'll edit that.. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's all I meant... copying the rest is of course ok.